# How to make the whole span clickable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to make the whole span clickable instead of only the input area. as the input is of submit type How can I do that?

```
<span id="finishspan" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd">
<input type='submit' id="finish" name='finish' value='Finish'/>
</span>
```

and this is the jquery code

```
 $("#finish").click(function(){

    $('#finishspan').prepend('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    $("#finish").val("Store creating...");

 });
```

Comment: It’s clickable. You just have to listen for the event. So instead of listening for the event on the input, listen on the span itself. And you’re done.

Comment: no i am not done when i change click function to span form is not submitting....

Comment: Does `$("#finishspan").click(function(){` not do the trick?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no tried this, the form is not submitting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your HTML with a `form` tag. Then change the selector to the `id` of the `span`. Finally submit the form manually inside the click handler function:

```js
$("#finishspan").click(function(){
    $('#finishspan').prepend('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    $("#finish").val("Store creating...");
    $("#myform").submit();
 });
```

```css
#finishspan {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <span id="finishspan" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd">
    <input type='submit' id="finish" name='finish' value='Finish'/>
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to make span display block or use div.

```
span#finishspan {
    display: block;
}
```